# pathForResource Not Working on ios6

Tags: ios

Sorry if this is elementary. Banging my head over it. My app works fine in iOS5.1 and below, but fails to reach my .txt files in my Supporting Files folder in ios6. It always returns "null". I researched this and have checked the Bundle, all is there. The table lists about 8 speakers. On click, it is supposed to pull a DetailView loaded from a .txt file.

...[code]...

```
else if (self.makeLabel.text == @"Peter Sengenberger") {
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sengenberger" ofType:@"txt"];

            if (filePath) {
                NSString *myText1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                if (myText1) {

                    textData= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0, 280,200)]; //size.height-30 )];
                    textData.text = myText1;
                    [textData setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                    [textData setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    [textData setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                    textData.editable = NO;
                    textData.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;



                    [textScroll addSubview:textData];

                }

            }

        } // end if
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *Copied* the file to the bundle, actually?

Comment: Yes, copied to the bundle. I don't know why 5.1 finds it and 6.0 doesn't. Thanks for any help. I am still looking...